# Convert negative sign values of a DataFrame into a Parenthesis

Tags: python, pandas

I have set up DF number formatting with - pd.options.display.float_format='{:,.0f}'.format

However this is resulting negative values to display ex.,-100,000. I would like the value to display as (100,000). Help is appreciated

Comment: Can you provide input and expected output?

Comment: @NarendraPrasath -1 --> (1)

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov Okay but the question title stated that need to convert  to paranthesis. You can use `abs` function in dataframe or series for converting negative numbers to positive number.

Comment: the ask is not to represent negative value as positive. rather change the sign from - to ().

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1, -23]})
print(df)
    a
0   1
1 -23
```

---

```
df.astype(str).a.str.replace("^-([0-9]*)", "(\\1)")
0       1
1    (23)
Name: a, dtype: object
```

Note: what you're asking for is only for presentational purposes.

For decimals you may try:

```
df.a.astype(str).str.replace("^-([0-9.]*)", "(\\1)")
0       1.0
1    (23.0)
Name: a, dtype: object
```

or, if you wish:

```
df.a.astype(str).str.replace("^-([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)", "(\\1)")
0       1.0
1    (23.0)
Name: a, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks. But i am working with Financial Data and the number format is 'float64'.